# Java FX 3D light rendering problem on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, javafx, 3d, javafx-3d

I am trying to use JavaFX3D to display 3D shapes but there is a problem with them rendering. The light is not working properly, filling darker sides with solid black color. I am using Sonoma 14.2.1 on MacBook Air M2 and JAVAFX sdk 21.0.1. I tried using both Java JDK 20 and 17.

The code I used is from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBjwBmH8OhQ) and expected this result:
[properly working box render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faqmw.gif)

Instead I result in this:
[my box render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP2Sz.gif)

The same happens to the sphere shape:
[my sphere render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9LOu.png)

This is a code I used:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @author afsal villan
 * @version 1.0
 *
 * http://www.genuinecoder.com
 */
public class DrawingBox extends Application {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 1000;

    private double anchorX, anchorY;
    private double anchorAngleX = 0;
    private double anchorAngleY = 0;
    private final DoubleProperty angleX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private final DoubleProperty angleY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Box box = new Box(100, 20, 50);
        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
        material.setDiffuseColor(Color.AQUA);
        box.setMaterial(material);

        SmartGroup group = new SmartGroup();
        group.getChildren().add(box);

        Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        scene.setFill(Color.SILVER);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        group.translateXProperty().set(WIDTH / 2);
        group.translateYProperty().set(HEIGHT / 2);
        group.translateZProperty().set(-1500);

        initMouseControl(group, scene);

        primaryStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case Z:
                    group.translateZProperty().set(group.getTranslateZ() + 100);
                    break;
                case X:
                    group.translateZProperty().set(group.getTranslateZ() - 100);
                    break;
                case S:
                    group.rotateByX(10);
                    break;
                case W:
                    group.rotateByX(-10);
                    break;
                case D:
                    group.rotateByY(10);
                    break;
                case A:
                    group.rotateByY(-10);
                    break;
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Genuine Coder");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void initMouseControl(SmartGroup group, Scene scene) {
        Rotate xRotate;
        Rotate yRotate;
        group.getTransforms().addAll(
                xRotate = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS),
                yRotate = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS)
        );
        xRotate.angleProperty().bind(angleX);
        yRotate.angleProperty().bind(angleY);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            anchorX = event.getSceneX();
            anchorY = event.getSceneY();
            anchorAngleX = angleX.get();
            anchorAngleY = angleY.get();
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            angleX.set(anchorAngleX - (anchorY - event.getSceneY()));
            angleY.set(anchorAngleY + anchorX - event.getSceneX());
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class SmartGroup extends Group {

        Rotate r;
        Transform t = new Rotate();

        void rotateByX(int ang) {
            r = new Rotate(ang, Rotate.X_AXIS);
            t = t.createConcatenation(r);
            this.getTransforms().clear();
            this.getTransforms().addAll(t);
        }

        void rotateByY(int ang) {
            r = new Rotate(ang, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
            t = t.createConcatenation(r);
            this.getTransforms().clear();
            this.getTransforms().addAll(t);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** We tested it on two other MacBooks, one with Sonoma installed, and one with the older - Ventura version. The **Ventura version worked just fine**, while **Sonoma failed** the same way.

Comment: That is kind of weird looking.  I wonder if you didn't [switch depth buffering on](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean)).  But that is just speculation. If you want debug help, provide the code in the question as a [mcve] so it can be replicated and not via a link to a youtube video or some offsite resource.

Comment: [Example 3D app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723429/how-to-make-a-scaled-javafx-3d-texture-pixel-perfect-at-different-distances/77749316#77749316) and another [Example 3D app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77730183/how-can-i-make-a-node-rotate-around-a-circle-using-the-path-transition-method/77731026#77731026).  Try running them on your system and see if get the same output as the screenshots that accompany the examples.

Answer (score 4):

[Mesh rendering correctly on a M1 Mac running Mac OS 13.6.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToPWJ.png)

[Mesh Rendering issue on M2 Mac running Mac OS 14.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSUPI.png)

I also have JavaFX 21 Mesh PointLight/AmbientLight rendering issues on a M2 MacBookPro running Mac OS 14.2.1 (Sonoma) but NOT on an M1 MacBookAir running Mac OS 13.6.3. So this may be a Sonoma 14.2.1 issue. My example program, is from pages 254-267 of the Apress book "*JavaFX 8 Introduction by Example*", 2014, by C Dea, M. Heckler. G. Grunwald, J. Pereda, and S. Phillips.

Comment: If you believe you have discovered a bug, consider following the steps to [submit a bug report](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report) and then linking to the issue reference here so that others who have a similar issue can track it.

Comment: For further contextual information, I have created JavaFX 3D apps that render fine (those linked in my previous comment on the question) with JavaFX 21.0.1 running on Sonoma 14.1.2 on an *Intel* mac.

Comment: There were some [Sonoma related issues regarding JavaFX in the 21 release of JavaFX that were addressed in the 21.0.1 release](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8319669?jql=text%20~%20%22javafx%20sonoma%22) and also others with pre-release versions of Sonoma.  Those issues may have been completely unrelated to your rendering issue (I don't know).  Please ensure that you are testing with JavaFX 21.0.1 and all recent OS X updates at a minimum.

Comment: I have checked and my example which has lighting issues. It was created using Eclipse 2023-12 with openJDK 21.0.1 and javaFx 21.0.1 sdk. The  program written and executed on a M2 MacBookPro with 96GB of memory. I actually found the problem while working on a 3D graphics program for

Comment: @jewelsea:  I have checked and my basic mesh example which has lighting issues was created using Eclipse 2023-12 with openJDK 21.0.1 and javaFx 21.0.1 sdk. This example was written and executed on a M2 MacBookPro with 96GB of memory. The program runs **without** PointLight-AmbientLighting issues on a M1 MacBook Air with 16GB of memory.   I actually found the problem while working on  a much more complex program for teaching differential geometry.  In any case, I will also try this example on an Intel iMac running MacOS 14.2.1 soon!  Thank you (@jewelsea) for responding!

Comment: It could be an issue with the JavaFX es2 3D rendering pipeline on M2 series Macs on Sonoma (I don't know, I don't have the appropriate hardware to validate it).  There is a major upgrade proposed to the Mac 3D graphics pipeline to [use the Apple Metal API instead of OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76825116/does-javafx-use-the-new-metal-based-rendering-for-java-on-macos), as noted in the umbrella issue [JDK-8271024 ☂ JavaFX : Implement Metal Rendering Pipeline](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8271024), but that is incomplete, it won't help in the near term.

Comment: Today, I ran my example on a _6-core Intel 16GB_ iMac running MacOS 14.2.1 **without** the PointLight-AmbientLight rendering issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix for my program and the basic program above: Under MacOS Ventura, there is no need to specify a PhongMaterial's specular color **only** the ambient color is necessary, but under MacOS Sonoma, you need to specify **both** the ambient color and the specular color. This means that, for some reason, the lighting calculations are being done differently.

Answer (score -1):

Today, I ran my example on a *6-core Intel 16GB* iMac running MacOS 14.2.1 **without** the PointLight-AmbientLight rendering issues. @jewelsea, thanks for following up! I've also read somewhere that Apple depreciated OpenGL in favor of  Apple Metal.

Answer (score -1):

I submitted a bug report for this a few months ago. From https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8318985:

> After debugging with some default values in shaders, it looks like this issue is related to how to we default specular values in shaders.
> From the Java side even when we don't have specular parameters we set (1, 1, 1, 32) value and in case of OpenGL shader when specular is not set we use (0, 0, 0, 0). If we use 32 specular power with 0 attenuation (0, 0, 0, 32) we see appropriate output. Looks like some of these default values are interpreted differently in aarch64 vs x64 scenario.

Setting the specular color fixed it for me.